# What is the effect of vibrations on an object's properties?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, moment-of-inertia, vibrations

What do vibrations do to an object's properties? By making an object vibrate at a high frequency (compared to its static state) would vibrations:

- Increase or reduce its moment of inertia?
- Increase toughness?
- Change Newton's equation $F=ma$ (increase the force or reduce it)?
- Decrease the impact of an applied force (absorbing it) or increase it?

Comment: Why would you think it would do *any* of these things?